# How to change case of a file in git under cygwin?

Tags: git

We work in a mixed case sensitive/insensitive environment (cywgin/linux), and today someone created a small havoc in our workflow by renaming a file, changing an S to an s. This caused all sorts of interesting merge issues across branches, and to be quite honest no-one's entirely sure of what happened.

What is the most appropriate way to change casing of a file under git for cygwin? I must stress that we *are* case sensitive and normally do this right - if it wasn't for that S.

Comment: I've never used git under cygwin - does `git mv` not check in the rename properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having thought about it a couple minutes, it seems very likely `git-mv` would do what you need to. I'm fairly sure that it will attempt the rename (which might be a no-op on a a case-insensitive OS) then add the rename to the index. This should be based on the arguments, not on the actual file - I see `rename_cache_entry_at(pos, dst);` in builtin-mv.c.

I'm not sure if this is part of what you're asking or not, but with respect to your branch chaos, here's the general approach you probably want to take:

- Commit the rename fix to all of your "farthest downward" branches. These are probably topic and maintenance branches - the ones that are merged into other branches, but never have branches merged to them
- Merge these branches as per your normal workflow, fixing any conflicts that may result from the rename.
- Encourage everyone to pull soon, just in case the issue has a way to propagate further. For example, someone could work on the renamed file, *then* pull, and fix the rename conflict the wrong way, resulting in a state which would recreate the problem when pushed/pulled.

Comment: For others who find this, you will need to use "git mv -f" to force the rename, because Cygwin will complain that the source and destination are the same.

Answer (score 4):

I just had a problem similar to this where I just wanted to rename a directory, 'Scripts', to 'scripts'. I am currently working in Cygwin so it wasn't quite so easy. If I attempt to do it as I would in GNU/Linux, I get an error.

```
$ git mv foo Foo
fatal: renaming foo failed: Invalid argument
```

However, I realized I could bypass what I assume are Windows' shortcomings by moving twice, first to a name that doesn't collide, and then to the actually desired name.

```
$ git mv foo Foo2 && git mv Foo2 Foo
```

I had stashed my working tree away for this change though so I could commit it separately and evidently didn't think things through because now the files beneath the directory that I moved fail to merge from the stash to my tree. :-/ In my case, it's a minor problem though (and to be safe, I tarballed the tree before attempting this, I so I can always just do it the forceful unversioned way... :P).

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to point that as a *fallback* you can manipulate entries in index (the staging area), from where you would be able to commit with "git commit" (not "git commit -a") with **[git update-index](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-update-index.html)** plumbing (low level) command.

Answer (score 0):

Does your cygwin correctly recognize user's group name? I can be not recognized group issue. You may want to check this [chmod cannot change group permission on cygwin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17091972/chmod-cannot-change-group-permission-on-cygwin/38048219#38048219)