# git mv and only change case of directory

Tags: macos, git, version-control, case-sensitive

While I found similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1596653/how-to-change-case-of-a-file-in-git-under-cygwin) I didn't find an answer to my problem

When I try to rename the directory from FOO to foo via `git mv FOO foo` I get

```
fatal: renaming 'FOO' failed: Invalid argument
```

OK. So I try `git mv FOO foo2 && git mv foo2 foo`

But when I try to commit via `git commit .` I get

```
# On branch master
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
# foo
nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

When I add the directory via `git add foo` nothing changes and `git commit .` gives me the same message again.

What am I doing wrong? I thought I'm using a case-sensitive system (OSX) why can't I simply rename the directory?

Comment: OS X's file system isn't case-sensitive.

Comment: @mipadi It can operate in case-sensitive mode but that's usually off by default.

Comment: This question & its answers are useful in Windows, too. Consider untagging "osx"

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/24979063/6309: since git 2.0.1, a simple `git mv` works.

Comment: On windows youo can use the regular `git mv foo Foo` if you use a cygwin shell.

Comment: A couple of days ago I reported the "Invalid argument" error mentioned here to the Git mailing list as a bug, which it seems nobody ever did previously over the 11 years and 86000 views since this question was opened. Here's the thread: https://lore.kernel.org/git/CAD8jeghpOQoibk0xM0QgLsOwLNw9GdM=4rhYuzV-NSkw8LinMQ@mail.gmail.com/. Maybe this will be fixed in a new release in the near future.

Answer (score 482, accepted):

You are in a case insensitive environment. Further, adding without the `-A` will not take care of the remove side of the `mv` as Git understands it. **Warning! Ensure that no other changes or untracked files are around when you do this or they will get committed as part of this change!** `git stash -u` first, do this and then `git stash pop` after. Continuing: To get around this, do the following:

```
mv foo foo2
git add -A
git commit -m "renaming"
mv foo2 FOO
git add -A
git commit --amend -m "renamed foo to FOO"
```

That's the drawn out way of changing the working directory, committing and then collapsing the 2 commits. You can just move the file in the index, but to someone that is new to git, it may not be explicit enough as to what is happening. The shorter version is

```
git mv foo foo2
git mv foo2 FOO
git commit -m "changed case of dir"
```

As suggested in one of the comments, you can also do an interactive rebase (`git rebase -i HEAD~5` if the wrong case was introduced 5 commits ago) to fix the case there and not have the wrong case appear anywhere in the history at all. You have to be careful if you do this as the commit hashes from then on will be different and others will have to rebase or re-merge their work with that recent past of the branch.

This is related to correcting the name of a file: [Is git not case sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8481488/is-git-not-case-sensitive/8481559)

Comment: Thanks. This was driving me crazy. I didn't know about the -A or the --amend option.

Comment: Careful with the -A, since it will recursively add all content in your current directory, including untracked stuff. Might be better to just `git add foo2`.

Comment: That is correct. However you will need to stage both the removal of foo2 as well as the addition of FOO separately. `-A` takes care of both. Vice versa for the first step. I'll add the warning. Thanks!

Comment: You can also clean up your history with an interactive rebase `git rebase -i HEAD~2`. Note: To simplify this, set the final message in your first commit and fixup the second one.

Comment: First method works great in Windows (second one doesn't)

Comment: Tested the shorter version works on OSX, git version 2.3.2 (Apple Git-55), and also on Windows git version 1.8.3.msysgit.0.  (with git's default config core.ignorecase = true)

Comment: This is an overkill when there's `git mv -f`.

Comment: I had success with 
git mv foo foo2; git mv foo2 FOO; git commit

Comment: This fails after you quit Xcode and relaunch your project.  Tested in Xcode 6.3

Comment: it's 2022, I still had to go for renaming solution `git mv foo foo2; git mv foo2 FOO; git commit` as suggested. Thought things would have change to detect case sensitvity.

Answer (score 166):

You want to set the option `core.ignorecase` to false, which will make Git pay attention to case on file systems that don't natively support it. To enable in your repo:

```
$ git config core.ignorecase false
```

Then you can rename the file with `git mv` and it'll work as expected.

Comment: I think this may have undesirable effects elsewhere. Case insensitive systems should let Git think that it's the same dir.

Comment: I added the option to my global config but it didn't help

Comment: I see some weird behavior using this with OSX.  hrm `I modified a file that doesn't exist` .. hrm `error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout:` but ... those files don't exist.

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for. I am running CentOS 5.6 and it did not pick up the change of case.

Comment: Ya the marked correct answer didn't work AT ALL for me on OS X due to case-insensitive directories.  Not sure if this answer will solve it or not though.

Comment: Mine still says invalid argument even after setting this config.

Comment: Our dev machines are OSX, but the code runs in a VM under CentOS. This saved me so many headaches.

Comment: This doesn't work!  On Git 1.8.3, Git will treat the renamed file as a new file, instead of removed + added.  Committing such will leave the repository with two same file, e.g. foo and FOO both exist!  But when checkout only one file appear (but one case may dominate over the other case)

Comment: `git mv -f` is a better option to avoid dealing with the hassle of leftover files.

Answer (score 97):

I was able to resolve this, using git 1.7.7 by using a temporary filename:

```
$ git mv improper_Case improve_case2
$ git mv improve_case2 improve_case
$ git commit -m "<your message>"
```

Comment: Interesting. Maybe GIT improved something since then. When I'll stumble upon this problem again, I'll try this again.

Comment: much easier doing it this way

Comment: Worked for me on macOS.

Answer (score 22):

(`git mv`-free variant.)

I ran into this problem in Git on Mac OS X 10.9. I solved it as follows:

`git rm -r --cached /path/to/directory`

That stages the directory for deletion in Git but does not actually remove any physical files (`--cached`). This also makes the directory, now with the proper case, show up in untracked files.

So you can do this:

```
mv /path/to/directory /path/to/DIRECTORY
git add -A /path/to/DIRECTORY
```

Git will then recognize that you have renamed the files, and when you do `git status` you should see a number of `renamed:` lines. Inspect them and ensure they look correct, and if so, you can commit the changes normally.

Comment: I found that the `mv` command didn't work to actually rename the directory; I had to rename it within Finder. Other than that this fix works perfectly.

Comment: Worked perfectly as described for me, thank you!

Comment: And if you're doing something in a case-insensitive OS like Windows (which is what I am doing), you can rename the folder to something completely different before renaming it to the correct case (otherwise Windows will ignore the rename).  Worked like a charm for me.

Answer (score 13):

#### This is a quick and bug-safe solution:

```
git mv -f path/to/foo/* path/to/FOO/
```

#### Warning! Always rename all files in the renamed folder (use `/*`).

Do not rename single files. This leads to a bug, described in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30787229/2790048).

If you first want to see the outcome first, use `-n`:

```
git mv -f -n path/to/foo/* path/to/FOO/
```

After you've made an `mv`:

1. Commit changes
2. Checkout to any other revision
3. Checkout back.

Now Git should have renamed the folder BOTH in its internal files and in file system.

Comment: Is this only for Git 2.0.1 as I mentioned in the question comments above? (referring to http://stackoverflow.com/a/24979063/6309)

Answer (score 9):

Force it with -f option:

```
git mv -f FOO foo
```

Comment: Not work for me.  My setting is .git/config's "ignorecase = true".  The rename cannot be staged in staging area by this way.  (Git version 1.8.3.msysgit.0)   Adam Dymitruk's solution is the only right answer.

Comment: @JohnnyWong change your setting to `false`, it worked for me

Comment: Will this then update on all other user's computers if they pull, even if their computer is set to ignore case?

Comment: @Bryce No, you will need to commit the changes and push them to the central repo before other users can pull the changes.

Answer (score 6):

I had one related issue.

One folder named 'Pro' (created first) and another 'pro' (created by mistake). In Mac, it is the same thing, but different according to git.

```
$ git config core.ignorecase false
```

the git config rename the files to the right folder(thanks), and also created ghost files in 'pro' (No!!). I could not add ghost file changes to the track and I could not checkout other branches unless carry those those files with me, and i also could not reset it somehow.

Instead of that, i did

```
$ git rm -r --cached pro
$ git status // => pro files removed, new Pro files untracked
$ git add Pro
```

To make it extra safe, i did it in a separated fix branch, and then i merged back to main branch

For the ghost file issue created by , can any guru explain How and Why? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You're not using a case-sensitive filesystem in OS X unless you explicitly choose such. HFS+ *can* be case-sensitive, but the default is case-insensitive.

Comment: Using the case-sensitive file system on OS X is not a good idea.  A lot of apps do NOT work correctly, I learned from trying this.  One particular problem is that Adobe Photoshop will refuse to install saying that case-sensitive file system is not supported.

Answer (score 2):

This worked great for me on Windows. Used powershell with the following:

1. `mv .\Folder-With-Wrong-Casing .\temp`
2. `git add -A`
3. `git commit -m "renamed folder with wrong casing to temp"`
4. `mv .\temp .\Folder-with-Correct-Casing`
5. `git add -A`
6. `git commit --amend -m "Renamed to proper casing"`
7. (optional) `git push`

Thanks to Adam's answer above.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple way of doing it.

1. Make sure your working directory is empty.
2. Temporarily disable git ignore case

```sh
git config core.ignorecase false
```

3. Rename any directories (e.g. Folder => folder)
4. Add changes to working directory

```sh
git add --all
```

5. Stash your changes.

```sh
git stash
```

6. The original directories should be now deleted. Make a local commit.

```sh
git add --all
git commit -m "Rename directories"
```

7. Pop changes

```sh
git stash pop
```

8. Amend this to your previous commit.

```sh
git add --all
git commit --amend
```

9. You should now have a commit with directories renamed. You may now restore the original ignorecase config:

```sh
git config core.ignorecase true
```

Answer (score 1):

Improving Adam Dymitruk's answer (silly that SO doesn't let me comment his answer), using "git mv" will automatically stage exactly the moved files. No stashing is needed and the risky "git add -A" can be avoided:

```
old="abc";    new="ABC";
tmp="$old-renamed";
git mv "$old" "$tmp";
git commit -m "Renamed '$old' to '$tmp'.";
git mv "$tmp" "$new";
git commit --amend -m "Renamed '$old' to '$new'.";
```

Answer (score 1):

**Here's a really simple solution around all the gitfoo on this page.**

1. Copy the files out of your project manually.
2. git rm all the files.
3. git commit like normal.
4. add the files back manually.
5. git add all the files.
6. git commit like normal.
7. profit.

Comment: This works locally, but if someone else does a pull it won't change their case.

Comment: Thanks for this in helping me fix the double entries in git with different cases. I used a variant of this. Just renamed the parent folder. Did a commit. Then renamed parent folder back to original. And did a second commit. Now the older entries with the different case are gone.