# git fails because of an untracked working tree file

Tags: git, merge, branch, repository, github

I'm not an expert at google. Needless to say, I'm not even sure what this means or how to resolve it?

```
>> git merge admin_playground
error: Untracked working tree file 'vendor/gems/panda-1.0.0/.gitignore' would be overwritten by merge.
fatal: merging of trees 538b2824765956cc44c42a8ad628e4f4 and d5d4cda68518cd1c81bf70ba8c339fea6 failed
```

I am trying to perform a git merge and getting this failing statement.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's because `.gitignore` isn't in your current branch (it's untracked), but it's in the branch you're trying to merge. Add the `.gitignore` file in question and commit, then try the merge again; or delete the `.gitignore` file if you don't need it and are happy with the one in the other branch.

Answer (score 4):

Note: [mipadi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/28804/mipadi) (author of the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4462434/6309)) also mentioned this error message in the context of [case conflicts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3011719/6309) between filenames on different branches.

If cleaning the untracked files is a valid option, then the extreme solution is mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5361169/6309) (a `git clean -f -d` would remove *all* untracked files *and directories*).
In your case, that could be overkill (or dangerous).

Another [original solution](http://www.druhosting.com/content/git-error-following-untracked-working-tree-files-would-be-overwritten-checkout):

```
git checkout -f admin_playground # will overwrite files
git checkout yourBranch # get back where you where when trying the merge
git merge admin_playground
```

> This forced git to go ahead and overwrite the files.
>   I assume you could have used the '`-f`' option with `merge` also, but switching to the other branch and then back fixed the issue and I was able to merge without any trouble the next time.

Note: there is actually no '`-f`' option on `git merge`.

Answer (score 2):

Try running below commands :

```
git add *

git stash

git pull
```