# git merge fails with "Untracked working tree file" on case change

Tags: git, macos, case-insensitive, branching-and-merging

On Mac OS X, I have two branches - say A and B - and I want to merge A into B. When I try to do `git merge A` on B, I get:

```
error: Untracked working tree file 'path/file.php' would be overwritten by merge.  Aborting
```

This is caused by the fact that some change in A renamed the file - i.e. B has file `path/File.php` while A has it renamed to `path/file.php`. Since Mac OS X filesystem is case insensitive, this probably confuses git. Is there a way to make git do the merge properly?

Update: for clarification, branch B does not have any uncommitted changes and the file in question is tracked in both branches (under different names, of course).

Comment: Note: with git2.0.1+, this merge should now work. See [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24978756/6309)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this answer to another question will be helpful; you may just want to enable the option temporarily…

[git mv and only change case of directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3011625/git-mv-and-only-change-case-of-directory/3011719#3011719)

Comment: Actually, what worked for me is setting ignorecase to true, but anyway, problem solved, thanks.

Answer (score 5):

OK, after digging around all day, here's the solution I found:

========== The Situation ==========

I am developing on my branch "Hotdog"

My co-worker pushed his work to our master branch, including a file named "Hamburgersrule"

I merge master into my Hotdog branch.

My co-worker changes "Hamburgersrule" to "HamburgersRule", and pushes it to master.

========== The Problem ==========

When I try switching between Hotdog and Master, Git thinks some changes have occured. The case of HamburgersRule looks different to Git, but windows thinks it's just fine. Every time I try to merge, or checkout another branch, Git warns me that I will lose my unstaged files.

I can suppress the message by setting git config core.ignorecase true, but the underlying problem is still there, and ignoring case differences is what got us into this mess in the first place.

========== The Solution ==========

1: Do a Triple Rename on Master (to make sure the new file name is correct)
HamburgersRule -> HamburgersRule_Rename -> HamburgersRule

2: Merge that change into Hotdog Branch. To get the merge to work, you will need to delete your version of "Hamburgersrule" (using your OS, not git)

3: Clean up the remaining files on Hotdog. Check to see if the merge worked as expected. You might have to checkout HamburgersRule from the Master branch:

`git checkout master HamburgersRule`

EDIT:
Important note. If you don't want to keep fixing this problem over and over again, make sure your coworkers all have ignorecase set to false

`git config core.ignorecase false`

If anyone is ignoring case sensitivity, their git client will ignore the changes, and keep checking in the bad name.

Answer (score 3):

Starting git 2.0.1 (June 25, 2014), that merge won't fail anymore.

See [commit ae352c7f37ef2098e03ee86bc7fd75b210b17683](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ae352c7f37ef2098e03ee86bc7fd75b210b17683) by [David Turner (`dturner-tw`)](https://github.com/dturner-tw)

#### [`merge-recursive.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/ae352c7f37ef2098e03ee86bc7fd75b210b17683/merge-recursive.c): fix case-changing merge bug

> On a case-insensitive filesystem, when merging, a file would be wrongly deleted from the working tree if an incoming commit had renamed it changing only its case.
>   When merging a rename, the file with the old name would be deleted -- but since the filesystem considers the old name to be the same as the new name, the new file would in fact be deleted.
>
> We avoid this by not deleting files that have a case-clone in the index at stage 0.

Answer (score 0):

How about if you do a `git mv path/File.php path/file.php` on `B`?  This should let git know it's the same file with a different name.

Comment: Doesn't work, gives: `fatal: destination exists, source=path/File.php, destination=path/file.php`

Comment: Can you `git stash` your untracked changes and than `git stash pop` them off after the merge?

Comment: I do not have any untracked changes, that's the problem.