# Is git not case sensitive?

Tags: git, version-control, case-sensitive

In the first commitment of my partial called `_Electronics` it was written beginning with a capital letters, then I changed it to `_electronics`.

Git under cygwin ignored the case after commiting the new name, so I changed the name by hand in the target repo.

Now it sometimes changes the commited `_electronics` partial to `_Electronics`.

What have I done wrong?

Comment: What OS are you on?

Comment: What file system are you using?

Comment: Windows with cygwin. My server runs Ubuntu Linux. Don't know the file system, I guess ext3 or ext2 - my provider configured the minimal installation.

Comment: Aren't you glad Windows decided not to be case-sensitive?

Comment: Windows is not case-sensitive? are you sure?

Comment: Windows is case insensitive, but sometimes (more frequently today) case *preserving*.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

It will be seen as 2 different things but will cause you issues on a non-case-sensitive system. If this is the case, ensure you are tab-completing any paths or file names. Further, to change the name of something in just the case, do this:

```
mv file.txt temp.txt
git add -A
git commit -m "renaming..."
mv temp.txt File.txt
git add -A
git commit --amend -m "Renamed file.txt to File.txt"
```

This is an explicit way of making changes committing them, then collapsing the commits. A shorter way to do it is to manipulate the index and working folder all in one:

```
git mv file.txt temp.txt
git mv temp.txt File.txt
git commit -m "Renamed file.txt to File.txt"
```

This is related to adjusting directory names as well: [git mv and only change case of directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3011625/git-mv-and-only-change-case-of-directory/3011723#3011723)

Comment: looks like this was right (except that I was changing from capital letters to downcase)

Comment: I peeked into it, as long as I'm used to cygwin, it is just more comfortably to use cygwin - thanks for the hint

Comment: You can just do `git mv file.txt File.txt`. Not sure if this is a new git feature.

Answer (score 126):

It is going to depend on the `core.ignorecase` configuration value, which is set to false in case-sensitive filesystems and true in msysgit on Windows.

> core.ignorecase
>
> If true, this option enables various workarounds to enable git to work better on filesystems that are not case sensitive, like FAT. For
>   example, if a directory listing finds "makefile" when git expects
>   "Makefile", git will assume it is really the same file, and continue
>   to remember it as "Makefile".
>
> The default is false, except git-clone(1) or git-init(1) will probe and set core.ignorecase true if appropriate when the repository
>   is created.

More detail in this reply to [Changing capitalization of filenames in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33732203/123033).

Comment: This is the correct answer imo. For future me, use `git config --unset-all core.ignorecase && git config --system core.ignorecase false` with sudo.

Comment: @Znarkus On OS X, your code was EXACTLY what I needed.  Thank you!

Comment: ditto to James, @Znarkus has identified the fix for this problem on OS X, Thanks!

Comment: @Znarkus Works on Windows too. Beautiful.

Comment: @Znarkus, the problem with doing that on OSX is that when you rename a file through the finder, and only change the case, git will see the renamed version as a completely new file, but it doesn't generate a corresponding "delete" action for the old version of the file. So if you commit and push to github, github will have both the old-named and the newly-named file, but your local system will just have the new file, and git will be none the wiser.

Comment: @spiralganglion For web dev on OSX I can really recommend [creating a case sensitive partition](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9596248/138023) and then mount it as your www directory.

Comment: i went to very great lengths and weird things were done only get git go around git's insensitivity to letters only to find all i had to do was tell git to mind the case...there should be watch out list for windows users.

Answer (score 24):

This is far easier:

```
git mv Electronics electronics -f
git commit -m "That was easy!"
```

Comment: Did you try this on a case insensitive filesystem?

Comment: I initially read this as the original poster trying to perform a case-changing rename of a folder, not a file.  Now that I re-read this, it is unclear.  Indeed, `mv -f` will work for a file.

Answer (score 24):

```
git config --system core.ignorecase false
```

Answer (score 0):

In my scenario I had two folders `tests` and `Tests` which showed as two separate folders in Github but a single `Tests` folder in Windows. My aim was to combine them both into `tests`.

I used the following approach:

1. Create a new folder `temp`
2. Copy all content from `Tests` to `temp`
3. Delete `Tests`
4. execute `git rm Tests -r`
5. Rename `temp` to `tests`

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to solve the issue and it was successful on Windows10

Lets suppose there are two folders on bitbucket TEST and test but when I clone repo on disk it creates only TEST and I want to keep test as single folder on git which contains all files.

I will need to execute following commands on command line
git mv TEST test1 -f
git mv text1 test -f
git commit -m "renaming..."
git push

Now you will see that folder hierarchy is corrected on bitbucket.