# Simulating case sensitivity on a filesystem that isn't case sensitive

Tags: c++, macos, unix, g++

When I develop in C++ on a filesystem that is not case sensitive, I miss problems such as

```
#include "File.h"
```

if on disk it is actually `file.h`.

The problem only appears when I eventually try to compile the code on a case sensitive filesystem.

How do I simulate case sensitivity on a filesystem (such as OSX's default) that isn't case sensitive?

**Edit:**
I am looking for an automated solution, one that I can run now and in the future with "the push of a button".

It also appears to be perfectly good style to rigorously name files in C++ after the exact name of the class, including case. So SuperDuperClass would appear in SuperDuperClass.h. A solution that requires lowercasing filenames is not suitable.

Comment: Do you need to simulate case sensitivity, or is it enough to filter your source and convert to lowercase when necessary?

Comment: Probably best the build breaks on case mismatch. You want your code to compile independent of the filesystem.

Comment: @AndrewWhite Yes, absolutely. I am indeed looking for a way to make the build break even if I am on a system that is case insensitive.

Comment: @AdamLiss I'd like indeed to simulate case sensitivity.

Comment: Hpfs+ By default is not case sensitive??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On Mac OS X, you can use Disk Utility to create a case-sensitive file system on a disk image.

[image: case sensitive DMG]

Comment: This is just a little radical; wouldn't you say? All right, granted, I don't need to wipe my main disk and re-install the OS. It would be enough to use a USB flash drive, but is a software solution for this problem really so difficult?

Comment: You can use HFS+CS on a disk image. Added a picture to illustrate. :)

Answer (score 1):

I'll just throw this out there. Only use lower case filenames. However, I am interested in a more complete and verifiable answer.

Comment: What is unverifiable about the answer? You can easily search your source tree for filenames that are not all lower case, and also grep your #include directives to find instances like "File.h".

Comment: Also, develop such a habit that you never type #include "File.h" by accident.

Comment: I have now added an "Edit" section to clarify the question.

Answer (score 0):

I would be tempted to write something like FileMon (to run externally), and just monitor the file access calls from your IDE to the file system to check for case matches. It's unlikely you're going to get any automated checking from the IDE or the OS (at least, without mucking with the file system). On the other hand, a separate utility monitoring the file access could easily catch such issues (once you get over the hurtle of making the monitoring work).

My 2c, anyway.

Comment: Writing something like FileMon is hardly a brief exercise. In that case I might as well write a C++ preprocessor with the added functionality, but I am still hoping that there is a simple solution--one, for example, that points out to the offending lines by just combining a few standard unix utilities.