# Push a case sensitive change to remote repository

Tags: windows, git

On my local system, I had a file named `FarmApi`, whereas in my remote repository it was named `farmApi`. Having noticed that [and then read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8481488/is-git-not-case-sensitive), in my `.gitconfig` and in my `.git\config` I went ahead and set:

```
[core]
    ignorecase = false
```

That allows me to add, commit, and push the case sensitive change. The problem now is that the remote repository has both `farmApi` and `FarmApi` whereas our local has only `FarmApi`.

## Remote

[image: Remote]

## Local

[image: Local]

Why are the case sensitive changes out of sync? How do we remedy this?

Comment: Have you tried `git checkout auth`?

Comment: I'm already on `auth`, so I'm not sure what `checkout` will do that's any different.

Answer (score 1):

While I am not certain what steps you took, you ended up adding, rather than renaming, the file as far as Git is concerned (probably by renaming on your local machine without doing a `git mv`), thus you have the two copies in your repository. The reason why this is not reflected in your working directory is that the two files only differ by case, and on Windows (which I assume you are on) you cannot have files that only differ by case; they are considered the same file.

To get out of the situation, make a backup of the file, and then `git rm` it. Do a `git add --all` just to be sure, and then commit; this should get rid of both files on the repo. Then restore your backup and re-add the file.

Comment: It seems that case insensitivity is not such a good idea for an OS. I've heard that before and now I'm starting to understand.