# New to Heroku - "No such type as web"

Tags: python, heroku, web, flask

I'm trying to deploy my first app using Python/Flask on Heroku.  I don't really know what I'm doing and am just following the tutorial at https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python#prerequisites.  When I type the command `heroku ps:scale web=1` I'm getting the error message "`No such type as web`".  My `Procfile` says `web: python scrabble_cheater.py`, which I believe is correct.  Here's the log of my terminal:

```
(venv)jason-olsens-macbook-pro:scrabble paulnichols$ heroku status
=== Heroku Status
Development: No known issues at this time.
Production:  No known issues at this time.
(venv)jason-olsens-macbook-pro:scrabble paulnichols$ heroku config
=== enigmatic-mountain-1395 Config Vars
LANG:             en_US.UTF-8
LD_LIBRARY_PATH:  /app/.heroku/vendor/lib
LIBRARY_PATH:     /app/.heroku/vendor/lib
PATH:             /app/.heroku/venv/bin:/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin
PYTHONHASHSEED:   random
PYTHONHOME:       /app/.heroku/venv/
PYTHONPATH:       /app/
PYTHONUNBUFFERED: true
(venv)jason-olsens-macbook-pro:scrabble paulnichols$ heroku ps
(venv)jason-olsens-macbook-pro:scrabble paulnichols$ git push heroku master
Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '50.19.85.154' to the list of known hosts.
Everything up-to-date
(venv)jason-olsens-macbook-pro:scrabble paulnichols$ heroku ps:scale web=1
Scaling web processes... failed
 !    No such type as web
(venv)jason-olsens-macbook-pro:scrabble paulnichols$
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your blank `heroku ps` output suggests that there's something wrong with your `Procfile`. Make sure heroku can find it and it contains what you think it does.

Comment: I originally mis-named the procfile as lower-case, but I've corrected that.  I think I'm having trouble pushing it to the Heroku repo, but I don't know how to check.

Comment: You may have some trouble in a case-insensitive environment. If so, try [this trick](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3011723/1002469) with git to change the file's case. You can `git push` normally afterwards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Procfile was saved with a .txt extension by mistake--once I removed the extension it worked.