# XCode source control flashing

Tags: xcode, git, version-control

I'm seeing this spooky issue where XCode's source control indicators are flashing between two states.  It's hard to describe so I did a screen capture: http://youtu.be/j39Fn471qaE

Its doing it in two places: the navigation tree; and in the file detail inspector.

State 1
navigation pane - no source control indicator
source control pane - "Version: --" and "Status: No changes"

State 2
navigation pane - "A" for added
source control pane - "Version: Not yet committed" and "Status: A Added"

The git command line just shows those files as "new file".  The ones that are flashing seem to be no different to others that are not manifesting this behavior.

At present I'm just trying to keep working without letting it distract me and hoping its not a precursor to data loss....

Comment: You may open bug to apple at bugreport.apple.com.

Answer (score 0):

OK - the issue turned out to be caused by case sensitivity issues.  Mac OSX has the HFS+ file-system which is case-preserving, but case insensitive.

I had initially created a directory with a lower case letter and later changed it to upper case.  I guess XCode was polling for changes and when it checked for new files those files came up as new, but when it tried to mark them as added git said they were already in the repo.

The fix was to follow this procedure:  [git mv and only change case of directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3011625/git-mv-and-only-change-case-of-directory)