# Git and multiple copies of file with difference in casing

Tags: git, file-rename

I renamed one of the project file in Git from say My.Test to My.test. In the main repository, I am seeing both of copies of the project. Also, any changes that I am doing in My.test project are actually getting added in My.Test project in the main repository.

Scenario

```
1) Originally started with : My.Test
2) Renamed My.Test to My.test
3) Made changes in My.test
```

In main repo :

```
1) Both My.Test & My.test are getting listed
2) Changes done to My.test and getting listed in My.Test.
```

Any help in resolving this issue will be much appreciated.

Regards
Pawan Mishra

Answer (score 0):

A similar question has been discussed in the following forums

1. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/51346/how-do-i-rename-a-file-in-git-that-differs-by-case-only
2. http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/issues/detail?id=228
3. [git mv and only change case of directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3011625/git-mv-and-only-change-case-of-directory/3011723#3011723)