# Why would git log/status return no output?

Tags: git

I have a very old git repository (about six years old) and noticed that I wasn't seeing changes I'd made to a file in my `git status` output.

I ran the command on the specific file in question:

```
$ git status Data/schema.sql
$
```

and got no output! This file has been in the repo since the beginning. Additionally, if I checkout the repo to another directory, the file (strangely enough) appears there.

I saw the same with `git diff Data/schema.sql` and `git log Data/schema.sql`.

Normally, when something like this happens, it's a `gitignore` problem. But even removing my `.gitignore` file caused no change in this behavior.

What could cause this behavior?

Comment: are you sure Data/schema.sql is added to your stage changes ? (aka git add Data/schema.sql)

Comment: I tried `git add`. There was no output and it didn't change the output of `git status` or `git diff`.

Comment: Could it be an old git version installed on your server? or are you storing the code on github/bitbucket or something else ?

Comment: what happens if you do `git status [remote_name]/master`?

Comment: @NickVolynkin I get a number of dangling blobs, but no errors or problems.

Comment: Have you marked the file with a `skip-worktree` or `assume-unchanged` bit?

Comment: @Zeeker Not intentionally. Is there a way to check the bits assigned to the file?

Comment: `git ls-files -v | grep -i '^S'` should return all files marked in such a way.

Comment: @Zeeker It's not marked that way, but that did help me - it shows up in the list as "data/schema.sql" (no capital "D"). `git log data/schema.sql` works as expected. Thanks for the tip about `git ls-files`! Now, how do I fix this? `ls-files` shows some entries as `Data/blah.sql` and some as `data/blah.sql`

Comment: i.e. How do I get the directory name to be capitalized the same way everywhere in git's view?

Comment: @NickVolynkin Worked perfectly! Thanks for your help. If you rewrite this as an answer, I'd gladly accept the answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80305/discussion-between-nick-volynkin-and-bill).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This "symptom" has two possible "diagnoses":

## A case-insensitive forced rename back in history

### Diagnostics:

```
git ls-files
```

Search for paths with different capitalizations:

```
some/path/foo
Some/path/bar
```

### Solution

```
git mv -f Some/path/* some/path/
```

It's important to move all files (`/*`) to the renamed path. Now they will all have a single path.

### Possible cause

There may be a situation when `some/path` has several files with it, tracked with different letter cases in the path. For such files providing an "incorrect" path to `git log` or `git status` results in abscense of some commits in the log output.

This bug is reproduceable with `git mv -f <path/file> <PATH/file>` on Git 1.9.5 and maybe on newer versions (will check later).

```
git log Some/path/foo
```

The log will **not** contain some commits made before the `git mv -f some/path/bar Some/path/bar` was executed.

## Files marked with a `skip-worktree` or `assume-unchanged bit`

Thanks to @Zeeker for this assumption.

### Diagnostics:

```
git ls-files -v | grep -E '^(S|[a-z])'
```

For additional information take a look at the [`git ls-files` documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-files).

Comment: OK. I'll have to check with Git 2.0.1 since there was a fix (http://stackoverflow.com/a/24979063/6309)

Comment: @NickVolynkin It was my suggestion, I merely fixed my own mistake. ;)

Comment: @Zeeker: I don't see a lot of people concerned of fixing their own mistakes. :)

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: check for other running git-clients.

I just had a similar issue: zero output from git.

`git status`, `git log`, `git fetch`: all the same. Nothing. An empty line and back to the command-prompt.

I would only get responses when I was in the parent directory, which was not a repository or in a different repository.
Also, I got errors and suggestions for mis-typed commands. So it was not totally dead. Just in hibernation - or something.

The first response that I found was to `git branches` which properly printed the known branches. So I played with branches and used `git checkout master` which gave me nothing and all the above commands had not changed. All nothing. When I tried to switch back to `develop` I got a clue:

```
fatal: Unable to create 'I:/foo/bar/repo/.git/index.lock': File exists.

Another git process seems to be running in this repository, e.g.
an editor opened by 'git commit'. Please make sure all processes
are terminated then try again. If it still fails, a git process
may have crashed in this repository earlier:
remove the file manually to continue.
```

I found a running git-UI-client (GitKraken in my case) and closed it. Fixed.
Maybe the problem had something to do with the fact that my repo was on a Windows network share.

Comment: Now this problem has three possible diagnoses :)

Comment: I didn't have the same but a similar one, git status was working but git log not. Restarting my session fixed it, probably another running git process(es) caused the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was doing `git log` in the deepest folder in windows. wasn't working. so I tried `git ls-files`. it was also not working

I went up through folders enough times, until `git ls-files` worked, and then used `git log` with the relative file path.

Don't have any idea what causes this, but this solved the problem for me. (at least temporarily)

Answer (score 0):

I find that if using the MINGW64 Bash shell that ships with some versions of git, their attempt to manage case sensitivity can cause this failure.  To fix the problem, "cd" with the correct capitalization.  In the example below, the correct directory name is "CalMAN App".  However, if you cd to "calman app" that works.  Unfortunately, it confuses git.

```
micha@mrosen-win1 MINGW64 ~/dev/CalMAN/src/CalMAN/calman 5 (master)
$ cd "calman app"

micha@mrosen-win1 MINGW64 ~/dev/CalMAN/src/CalMAN/calman 5/calman app (master)
$ git log .

micha@mrosen-win1 MINGW64 ~/dev/CalMAN/src/CalMAN/calman 5/calman app (master)
$ cd ..

micha@mrosen-win1 MINGW64 ~/dev/CalMAN/src/CalMAN/calman 5 (master)
$ cd "CalMAN App"/

micha@mrosen-win1 MINGW64 ~/dev/CalMAN/src/CalMAN/calman 5/CalMAN App (master)
$ git log .
commit 41d026ddf3282227932136245092aaabace4aded
...
```