# Git file name changes case on push

Tags: git, github

I am working with git on my local machine and pushing to a remote apache server. I had a file which I originally added and it was named `controllers`. I wanted to change this to `Controllers` with the uppercase file name. When I did this and pushed, my remote server keep showing the file as `controllers` with the lower case name. I removed the files from both local/remote and pushed again but the file keeps showing with the lower case name.

I tried `git config core.ignorecase false` but it did not work. My apache server allows for uppercase filenames so that's not the issue. Can't figure out what this is. Is there git cache I can clear to solve this. Driving me bananas.

Comment: Just to double check... which branch do you have checked on apache? Are you sure you're looking at the same branch?

Comment: @JDB yes, I only have one branch for the project and it is the master branch.

Comment: Have you compared the commit SHAs to make sure that your commit has actually made it to the server?

Comment: @JDB yup, same commit. What's strange is when I remove the file from the server it will create both `controllers` and `Controllers` when only `Controllers` exists on my local machine.

Comment: Ah... it's possible that your local git repo was confused by your operating system and didn't properly record the deletion of `controllers`. Are the files in the root directory? If so, run `git cat-file -p master^{tree}` and see if you've got two files recorded.

Comment: If it's not in the root, then run that command recursively using the SHA of each folder (aka tree) until you get to the right one.

Comment: @JDB I think you lead me down the right track. I did `git rm -r --cached controllers
` and it seems to work fine now.

Comment: Don't change `core.ignorecase`.  This is not an option for you to make changes to, this is a cache of what Git has detected your filesystem supports.  By changing it, you have made Git think that you are on a different type of filesystem, and you have disabled any safe operations that come along with that.

Comment: @EdwardThomson ummm...if I did change it, is there a way to revert the change?

Comment: Great to hear @bos570. If you want, I recommend answering your own question for the benefit of future readers (who knows... that might be you someday)

Comment: @JDB will do. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @bos570 Yes, for sure - just `git config core.ignorecase true` - no worries!  :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git mv and only change case of directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3011625/git-mv-and-only-change-case-of-directory)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that when I changed the file name git did not properly record the change. I remove the dir from the repo with

```
git rm -r --cached controllers
```

then added and committed back to repo and that seemed to fix it.