# Cloned project from GitHub missing a folder

Tags: git, unity-game-engine, github

https://github.com/BerkeSoysal/TOON_BLASH/tree/master/Assets

in assets file there seems to be one scripts/ folder and one Scripts/ folder.

[image]

I want to resolve this mess (I want only Scripts/), but when I cloned the project there seems to be only one Scripts folder.

[image: Terminal]

How could I sync them?

Comment: There is Scripts the folder and scripts the meta file. There is no mess

Comment: @BugFinder no, the problem is: There is two sciprts folders in GitHub page (scripts, Scripts) but not when I cloned them into my local.

Comment: Does this solve your problem https://www.hanselman.com/blog/git-is-casesensitive-and-your-filesystem-may-not-be-weird-folder-merging-on-windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is essentially that the file system on windows is not case sensitive, whilst GIT is. There are 2 folders with the same name but different capitalization in the repo.

You can either fix the error, for example by cloning the project on an OS that has a case sensitive file system, like linux and removing one of the folders.

I've done this in the past with Windows subsystem for linux (WSL)
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/

I'm using Azure devops so i've also renamed folders online to fix this kind of issue.

Another way is to enable case sensitivity for your specific folder on windows:

> `fsutil.exe file setCaseSensitiveInfo <path> enable`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/case-sensitivity#modify-case-sensitivity

You'd wanna create a new folder, enable case sensitivity on that folder and then clone in your git repo in that folder. That way you should see 2 files. You can then correct your mistake by removing the file and changing the folder back to not be case sensitive, or you can leave it as-is.

I personally clone all my repose in subfolders under the path `c:\repos` so i've just set that folder to be case sensitive. It gets somewhat annoying sometimes with powershell commands (like for dotnet or nuget) now needing proper capitalization but it helps a lot when renaming folders in git repos.

EDIT: like @alexandr mentioned, you can also use `git mv`

```sh
git mv foo foo2
git mv foo2 FOO
git commit -m "changed case of dir"
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3011723/4122889

Comment: Thanks, I solved it using git mv  (I moved all files in scripts to Scripts). May be if you include this solution I can mark it as accepted.