# chmod 400 command is giving wrong permissions -r--r-----

Tags: cygwin, chmod, pem

So I am trying to change the permissions for my ec2 .pem file with

```
chmod 400 key_ec2.pem
```

But afterward I keep getting

```
-r--r-----  1 Huanqing None   1692 Feb  3 11:26 key_ec2.pem
```

I am using Cygwin on Windows 8. Is there a setting I need to change?

Comment: Weird... also, this `None` group doesn't look very nice. What if you change the group to yours?

Comment: can you try                           sudo chmod 400 key_ec2.pem

Comment: @fedorqui How do I change the group to mine?

Comment: @Sorcrer It says "-bash: sudo: command not found"

Comment: run cygwin as root user by right clicking the shortcut and click run as administrator,then try ,chmod 400 key_ec2.pem

Comment: Type `users` to know the groups you belong to. Then, use `chgrp GROUP_NAME file` to change it.

Comment: @fedorqui When I type `users` I get nothing back

Comment: @Sorcrer when I type `su -` I get "su: user root does not exist"

Comment: run cygwin as root user by right clicking the shortcut and click run as administrator,then try ,chmod 400 key_ec2.pem

Comment: @Sorcrer Thanks so much for the help but that still didn't work. Same wrong permissions are given.

Comment: can you try this http://superuser.com/questions/397288/using-cygwin-in-windows-8-chmod-600-does-not-work-as-expected

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17091972/chmod-cannot-change-group-permission-on-cygwin

Comment: @QuinnLiu what do you get when you type `id`? It should show all the groups you belong to, together with the numbers.

Comment: @Sorcrer Your link worked how do I give you points since you answered my question correctly in a comment?

Comment: @QuinnLiu That's all right, Glad I could help to solve your issue. Anyway that answer belongs to someone else give him the point.