# Does Cygwin lock out chmod changes for system user?

Tags: cygwin, posix, chmod

Similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17091972/chmod-cannot-change-group-permission-on-cygwin) question, I am unable to unset execute permissions on files after recently upgrading Cygwin.

I have a file with the following permissions:

```
ls -l filename

-rw-rwxr--+ 1 gstrycker Users 1334935 Jan 26 09:23 filename
```

I'm trying to get rid of execute privileges, but running chmod -x or even chmod 0 does not seem to work now (note that it always did work for me before -- but I don't believe there were this many columns in the POSIX security permissions)

```
chmod 0 filename

ls -l filename

----rwx---+ 1 gstrycker Users 1334935 Jan 26 09:23 filename
```

Why can I not seem to be able to modify this central group of privileges now?  I've always been able to before.  I even tried to change the group owner, but that didn't seem to help.

I'm stuck -- any ideas?  Is this a new Cygwin bug?  Did Cygwin recently add columns to the POSIX permissions, and if so, how do I access these?

Comment: Update:  my real reason for asking this question is that all of my syntax highlighting changed!  Even if I can't change the POSIX permissions for these new fields, is there a way to modify the syntax highlighting to ignore these?  I don't like my usually non-executable files showing up as GREEN -- almost every file is highlighted this way now :-/

Comment: Update 2:  If I create a directory from WITHIN Cygwin, the permissions of the files in the new directory are all behaving normally.  The problem seems to occur when a directory is created by the Windows 7 OS.  All files in a Windows-created directory have their permissions locked-in for the system RWX.  Any ideas on how to change this?