# On win7, cygwin and git bash have different ideas about a file or folder's permission

Tags: git, permissions, window, cygwin, git-bash

In Cygwin, I set the permission of a folder "tmp"

```
$ chmod 600 tmp

$ ls -ld tmp
drw-------+ 1 leecy Users 0 Aug 15 10:56 tmp
```

But Git Bash (from Git for Windows) gets a different idea
of the permission:

```
$ ls -ld ~/tmp
drwxr-xr-x 1 leecy 1049089 0 Aug 15 10:56 /c/cygwin64/home/leecy/tmp/
```

I have researched, read, and tried out the suggestions (`chgrp`, `chown :Users`,  `setfacl`, etc) from the following posts but still could not find a solution:

- [Updating file permissions with git-bash on Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25730041/updating-file-permissions-with-git-bash-on-windows-7)
- [chmod cannot change group permission on cygwin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17091972/chmod-cannot-change-group-permission-on-cygwin)
- [Using Cygwin in Windows 8, chmod 600 does not work as expected?](https://superuser.com/questions/397288/using-cygwin-in-windows-8-chmod-600-does-not-work-as-expected/876913#876913)
- [cygwin's chmod behaves as working, but it does not work](https://superuser.com/questions/778313/cygwins-chmod-behaves-as-working-but-it-does-not-work)

By the way, this problem is believed to be the reason why my `git clone` operation
(which uses SSH) has recently stopped working.  In the above I am
demonstrating the problem with a test folder `tmp`, but in real life
the folder is actually my `.ssh` and my `git clone` recently started 
failing with an error of:

```
$ git clone ...
Cloning into 'foo'...
Bad owner or permissions on /home/leecy/.ssh/config
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

There may be some recent change related to the Windows Domain 
set up (done by the corporate IT people) that is related to this
problem -- the problem started to surface after that change.

Versions:

```
Cygwin: 2.8.2(0.313/5/3)
Git Bash: git version 2.14.1.windows.1
```

**Update**

Thanks for the suggestion by Doug Henderson (see it in the comment).
I tried using the command `setfacl -b -k`, it did remove
the extra non-standard POSIX permissions, but it did not
solve the problem.

Before using `setfacl -b -k`

```
$ getfacl tmp
# file: tmp
# owner: leecy
# group: Users
user::rw-
group::---
other:---
default:user::rwx
default:group::r-x
default:other:r-x
```

After using `setfacl -b -k`

```
leecy@USLEECY-C1 ~
$ setfacl -b -k tmp

leecy@USLEECY-C1 ~
$ getfacl tmp
# file: tmp
# owner: leecy
# group: Users
user::rw-
group::---
other:---
```

But that did not help

cygwin:

```
$ ls -ld tmp
drw------- 1 leecy Users 0 Aug 15 10:56 tmp
```

Git Bash:

```
$ ls -ld tmp
drwxr-xr-x 1 leecy 1049089 0 Aug 15 10:56 tmp/
```

**Update 2**

Using `getfacl` I examined closely what group the file is in, and
indeed `cygwin` and `git bash` have two different ideas

Cygwin

```
$ getfacl tmp
# file: tmp
# owner: leecy
# group: Users
user::rw-
group::---
other:---
```

Git Bash

```
$ getfacl tmp
# file: tmp
# owner: leecy
# group: 1049089 <unknown>
user::rwx
group::r-x
other:r-x
```

The number `1049089` may mean `Domain Users` in my system, but
this number seems to be understood by `cygwin` but not `git bash`.
I said that because my cygwin `/etc/group` has a line like this 
(this file was not there originally, I created it using the command
`mkgroup  -l -d > /etc/group` as suggested in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38048219))

```
Domain Users:S-1-5-21-1593251271-2640304127-1825641215-513:1049089:
```

I also tried the command `chgrp` and `chown`.  Both ran without error,
but is not taking effect (the number `545` is the group id for `Users`
that `cygwin` (but not `git bash`) understands)

No effect of `chgrp`

```
$ getfacl tmp
# file: tmp
# owner: leecy
# group: 1049089 <unknown>
user::rwx
group::r-x
other:r-x

$ chgrp 545 tmp

$ ls -ld tmp
drwxr-xr-x 1 leecy 1049089 0 Aug 15 10:56 tmp/

$ getfacl tmp
# file: tmp
# owner: leecy
# group: 1049089 <unknown>
user::rwx
group::r-x
other:r-x
```

No effect of `chown`

```
leecy@USLEECY-C1 MINGW64 ~
$ chown leecy.545 tmp

leecy@USLEECY-C1 MINGW64 ~
$ ls -ld tmp
drwxr-xr-x 1 leecy 1049089 0 Aug 15 10:56 tmp/

leecy@USLEECY-C1 MINGW64 ~
$ getfacl tmp
# file: tmp
# owner: leecy
# group: 1049089 <unknown>
user::rwx
group::r-x
other:r-x
```

Comment: cygwin has a git package. Why not use it ?

Comment: The `+` at the end of the permissions displayed by ls in cygwin is an indicator that there are additional permissions that do not fit the user/group/other, read/write/execute model. You can display those using the `getfacl` cygwin command, or the `icacls` windows command, or in the file explorer with right-click, properties. Check both the acls for the `tmp` directories, and their parent directory. You may find a default acl on one of those parents that modifies the expected permissions.

Comment: You should also check the contents of the git global configuration. On both cygwin and msys2, it may be in `~/.gitconfig`. I have configured them to play nice with each other. cygwin and msys2 use different methods to translate windows internal user ids and group ids to the unix style names and numbers. Compare the `/etc/nsswitch.conf` files for clues.

Comment: @DougHenderson -- Thanks for the suggestion!  I tried the command `setfact -b -k` . It did remove the extra non-standard POSIX permissions, but it did not solve the problem.  See my update in the question for the details.

Comment: I also looked at my `~/.gitconfig`.  I did not see anything related to permissions there.  The only directives in the files are `[user]`, `[credential]` and `[gui]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the suggestions (from Doug Henerson and from matzeri).  My
original question was about the difference in view of permission
by `cygwin` and `git bash`, but really what I wanted to achieve
is to get my `git` working again (It was failing with an error of

```
Bad owner or permissions on /home/leecy/.ssh/config
```

)

Thanks for the suggestion by matzeri.  I tried out the cygwin git and realized
that the error of git was not due to the
group permission setting of my `~/.ssh` or `~/.ssh/config`, rather
it is the the owner value of the files/folder.

In this case, the owner value should have been `leecy`, and the display
of `cygwin` and `git bash` suggested that it had been set correctly,
but that was not really the case.  I had to run the following
command once (in `cygwin`) to set the value correctly.

```
chown -R $USER ~/.ssh
```

After this change, both my `cygwin git` and `git bash` worked.

Below is the full transcipt of what I saw before and after the fix:

Before the fix, `cygwin` said the owner is `leecy`

```
$ ls -ld ~/.ssh
drw-------+ 1 leecy EMEA+Domain Users 0 Aug  8 22:18 /home/leecy/.ssh


$ ls -ld ~/.ssh/*
-rwxr-xr-x  1 leecy EMEA+Domain Users  135 Aug 16 13:35 /home/leecy/.ssh/agent.env
-rw-------  1 leecy EMEA+Domain Users  352 Jun  6 13:33 /home/leecy/.ssh/config
-rw-------  1 leecy EMEA+Domain Users 1766 May  8 19:32 /home/leecy/.ssh/id_rsa
-rwxr-xr-x  1 leecy EMEA+Domain Users  403 Jun  6 11:58 /home/leecy/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
-rw-r--r--  1 leecy EMEA+Domain Users 1582 Jun  6 11:50 /home/leecy/.ssh/known_hosts
```

( This change probably doesn't matter, but I did do it during my test. )

```
$ chmod 600 ~/.ssh/agent.env
```

`ssh` test was failing

```
$ ssh -v -p 29418 leecy@gerrit.app.foo.com
OpenSSH_7.5p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2k  26 Jan 2017
Bad owner or permissions on /home/leecy/.ssh/config
```

And then I ran this command

```
$ chown -R $USER ~/.ssh
```

On the surface, the value of owner are still the same

```
$ ls -ld ~/.ssh/*
-rw-------  1 leecy EMEA+Domain Users  135 Aug 16 13:35 /home/leecy/.ssh/agent.env
-rw-------  1 leecy EMEA+Domain Users  352 Jun  6 13:33 /home/leecy/.ssh/config
-rw-------  1 leecy EMEA+Domain Users 1766 May  8 19:32 /home/leecy/.ssh/id_rsa
-rwxr-xr-x  1 leecy EMEA+Domain Users  403 Jun  6 11:58 /home/leecy/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
-rw-r--r--  1 leecy EMEA+Domain Users 1582 Jun  6 11:50 /home/leecy/.ssh/known_hosts


$ ls -ld ~/.ssh
drw-------+ 1 leecy EMEA+Domain Users 0 Aug  8 22:18 /home/leecy/.ssh
```

But now my ssh works

```
$ ssh -v -p 29418 leecy@gerrit.app.foo.com
(worked)
```